# Arithmetic Encoding and Decoding Algorithm Python

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I am working on an adaptive implementation of arithmetic encoding and decoding algorithm and I've implemented it python but for some strings I'm getting the correct answer but for others I'm getting the correct answer.

When the program first starts, a parameter is provided to decide how often the probability of symbols will be changed. E.g., if the parameter is 10, then after transmitting/receiving 10 symbols the probability table is changed according to all symbols transmitted/received so far. Consequently the domain assignments are also changed. Initially, I have the uniform distribution [a-z] having 1/26 probability.

It does not work for "heloworldheloworld" and many other cases.

Also, I have learned about the underflow problem but how can I solve that problem.

```
import sys
import random
import string


def encode(encode_str, N):
    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

    low = 0
    high = float(1)/float(26)

    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
        low = high
        high += float(1)/float(26)

    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
        pdf[key] = float(1)/float(26)

    # for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
    #   print key, value

    # for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
    #   print key, value

    i = 26

    lower_bound = 0                                                                     # upper bound
    upper_bound = 1                                                                     # lower bound

    u = 0

    # go thru every symbol in the string
    for sym in encode_str:
        i += 1
        u += 1
        count[sym] += 1

        curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                          # current range
        upper_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][1])                    # upper_bound
        lower_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][0])                    # lower bound

        # update cdf_range after N symbols have been read
        if (u == N):
            u = 0

            for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                pdf[key] = float(count[key])/float(i)

            low = 0
            for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                high = pdf[key] + low
                cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                low = high

    return lower_bound

def decode(encoded, strlen, every):
    decoded_str = ""

    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

    low = 0
    high = float(1)/float(26)

    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
        low = high
        high += float(1)/float(26)

    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
        pdf[key] = float(1)/float(26)


    lower_bound = 0                                                                     # upper bound
    upper_bound = 1                                                                     # lower bound

    k = 0

    while (strlen != len(decoded_str)):
        for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):

            curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                      # current range
            upper_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][1])                 # upper_bound
            lower_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][0])                 # lower bound

            if (lower_cand <= encoded < upper_cand):
                k += 1
                decoded_str += key

                if (strlen == len(decoded_str)):
                    break

                upper_bound = upper_cand
                lower_bound = lower_cand

                count[key] += 1

                if (k == every):
                    k = 0
                    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                        pdf[key] = float(count[key])/float(26+len(decoded_str))

                    low = 0
                    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                        high = pdf[key] + low
                        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                        low = high

    print decoded_str

def main():
    count = 10
    encode_str = "yyyyuuuuyyyy"
    strlen = len(encode_str)
    every = 3
    encoded = encode(encode_str, every)
    decoded = decode(encoded, strlen, every)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So it doesn't work for `heloworldheloworld`. Does it throw an exception or produce not-expected output? Could you, please, clarify on that?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, I first encoded heloworldheloworld and then using the arithemtic encoding algorithm, I get back a float and I have to decode using that float to get the heloworldheloworld back but it is not working for this string but I works for other strings such as "yyyyhhhh" or "heloworld". There is no syntax error, it is the algorithm that goes wrong somewhere but I'm having a hard time tracing it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, because Python `float` has 53 bits of precision. You can not encode really long strings.

You may want to use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead of `floats` to get arbitrary precision

```
import sys
import random
import string

import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec=100

def encode(encode_str, N):
    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

    low = 0
    high = Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)

    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
        low = high
        high += Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)

    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
        pdf[key] = Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)

    # for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
    #   print key, value

    # for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
    #   print key, value

    i = 26

    lower_bound = 0                                                                     # upper bound
    upper_bound = 1                                                                     # lower bound

    u = 0

    # go thru every symbol in the string
    for sym in encode_str:
        i += 1
        u += 1
        count[sym] += 1

        curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                          # current range
        upper_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][1])                    # upper_bound
        lower_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][0])                    # lower bound

        # update cdf_range after N symbols have been read
        if (u == N):
            u = 0

            for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                pdf[key] = Decimal(count[key])/Decimal(i)

            low = 0
            for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                high = pdf[key] + low
                cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                low = high

    return lower_bound

def decode(encoded, strlen, every):
    decoded_str = ""

    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

    low = 0
    high = Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)

    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
        low = high
        high += Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)

    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
        pdf[key] = Decimal(1)/Decimal(26)


    lower_bound = 0                                                                     # upper bound
    upper_bound = 1                                                                     # lower bound

    k = 0

    while (strlen != len(decoded_str)):
        for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):

            curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                      # current range
            upper_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][1])                 # upper_bound
            lower_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][0])                 # lower bound

            if (lower_cand <= encoded < upper_cand):
                k += 1
                decoded_str += key

                if (strlen == len(decoded_str)):
                    break

                upper_bound = upper_cand
                lower_bound = lower_cand

                count[key] += 1

                if (k == every):
                    k = 0
                    for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                        pdf[key] = Decimal(count[key])/Decimal(26+len(decoded_str))

                    low = 0
                    for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                        high = pdf[key] + low
                        cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                        low = high

    print decoded_str

def main():
    count = 10
    encode_str = "heloworldheloworld"
    strlen = len(encode_str)
    every = 3
    encoded = encode(encode_str, every)
    decoded = decode(encoded, strlen, every)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is appearing at around 12 character length string. This is near the double precision used by python, and is probably causing your problems.

I did a quick test with the BigFloat library (which has arbitrary precision) and got the right answer:

```
import sys
import random
import string
from bigfloat import *

factor = BigFloat(1)/BigFloat(26)

def encode(encode_str, N):
    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

    with precision(200) + RoundTowardZero:
        low = 0
        high = factor

        for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
            cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
            low = high
            high += factor

        for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
            pdf[key] = factor

        # for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
        #   print key, value

        # for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
        #   print key, value

        i = 26

        lower_bound = 0                         # upper bound
        upper_bound = 1                         # lower bound

        u = 0

        # go thru every symbol in the string
        for sym in encode_str:
            i += 1
            u += 1
            count[sym] += 1

            curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                          # current range
            upper_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][1])                    # upper_bound
            lower_bound = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[sym][0])                    # lower bound

            # update cdf_range after N symbols have been read
            if (u == N):
                u = 0

                for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                    pdf[key] = BigFloat(count[key])/BigFloat(i)

                low = 0
                for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                    high = pdf[key] + low
                    cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                    low = high

    return lower_bound

def decode(encoded, strlen, every):
    decoded_str = ""

    count = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)                                        # probability table
    cdf_range = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    pdf = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)


    with precision(200) + RoundTowardZero:
        low = 0
        high = factor

        for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
            cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
            low = high
            high += factor

        for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
            pdf[key] = factor


        lower_bound = BigFloat(0)                           # upper bound
        upper_bound = BigFloat(1)                           # lower bound

        k = 0

        while (strlen != len(decoded_str)):
            for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):

                curr_range = upper_bound - lower_bound                                      # current range
                upper_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][1])                 # upper_bound
                lower_cand = lower_bound + (curr_range * cdf_range[key][0])                 # lower bound

                if (lower_cand <= encoded < upper_cand):
                    k += 1
                    decoded_str += key

                    if (strlen == len(decoded_str)):
                        break

                    upper_bound = upper_cand
                    lower_bound = lower_cand

                    count[key] += 1

                    if (k == every):
                        k = 0
                        for key, value in sorted(pdf.iteritems()):
                            pdf[key] = BigFloat(count[key])/BigFloat(26+len(decoded_str))

                        low = 0
                        for key, value in sorted(cdf_range.iteritems()):
                            high = pdf[key] + low
                            cdf_range[key] = [low, high]
                            low = high

        print decoded_str

def main():
    count = 10
    encode_str = "heloworldheloworld"
    strlen = len(encode_str)
    every = 3
    encoded = encode(encode_str, every)
    decoded = decode(encoded, strlen, every)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```